# Getting URL of a product from HTML Code through BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently trying to get the URL of a Supreme Product from their home shop site.

From this site: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/pants I'm trying to scrape this URL https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/pants/mj1czv0pa/jcyp91a8w through the use of Keywords. With the current code I don't even get an error but the response stays empty so I was hoping you guys could help me. If anything more is needed pls ask.
Kind Regards

CODE:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/"
product_category = "pants"
size = []
product_keywords = ["Supreme®/The North Face®"]
product_style = ["Brown"]

def get_url():
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(baseurl + "shop/all/" + product_category)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    for keyword in product_keywords:
        if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
            for keyword in product_style:
                if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
                    url = soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"})["href"]
                    print(url)
                    return(url)
z = get_url()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on line 15 you have this "if conditional check":

```py
if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
    ...
```

So I tried to print the value of `soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text` and `keyword` and I got this :

```py
print(soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text, keyword, sep="\n")
```

```
$ python main.py
Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Pant
Supreme®/The North Face®
```

So your function does not return anything because this condition is not checked.

Now, just change `product_keywords` to

```py
product_keywords = ["Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Pant"]
```

BUT, your code as a major problem, see you have a for loop, if an another for loop with the SAME variable asignated :

```
for keyword in product_keywords:
    ...
    for keyword in product_style:
        ...
```

You really should replace the 2nd variable (maybe just with `keyword2`)

Then, you run the same check twice, you dont have to do that :

```py
if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
    ...
    if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
        ...
```

Because the keyword variable as not changed. So just remove the 2nd if.

And finally, after that, your code just works fine :)

Here is the modified working code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/"
product_category = "pants"
size = []
product_keywords = ["Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Pant"]
product_style = ["Brown"]

def get_url():
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(baseurl + "shop/all/" + product_category)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    for keyword in product_keywords:
        if soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text == keyword:
            for keyword2 in product_style:
                url = soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"})["href"]
                print(url)
                return(url)
z = get_url()
```

```bash
$ python main.py
/shop/pants/dezoyr6kq/hpjaigwrt
```

Comment: Okay so now a new problem has occurred. 
When searching the product name like this:
`print(soup.find("a", {"class" : "name-link"}).text, keyword, sep="\n")`
It only gives the first object found correct? But this is not  the product I want  to scrape.
The Pants I tried were not "Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Pant"
but the "Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Fleece Pant" and as soon as I adjust this in the keywords to the correct one I get it empty again.
And the check I did twice shouldn't be the same the first one to get the correct model (fleece pant) second for the colour brown

Comment: So with your method (which still helped me a lot thank you for that!) I do get a url but not the one from the original product I wanted to scrape. Those are different brown pants while I'm trying to get the brown fleece pants. Hopefully what I'm saying is understandable